# Using django tag in a div ID

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to generate dynamically an ID in my app using bootstrap dropdown menu but for some reason it does not appear ..

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-canvas dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Compare with
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    {% for i in team_list_pop %}
      <a class="dropdown-item" id="{{i.first_name}}" href="#">{{i.first_name}} {{i.last_name}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

and the output when I do inspect in my browser

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">John Doe</a>
```

with no traces of the ID. how can I get to hve an output

```
<a id="john" class="dropdown-item" href="#">John Doe</a>
```

thx you very much

Comment: is the field `first_name` correct? Perhaps just try and show a list first?

Comment: yes it is because in the href it is rendering properly

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look if the value you are typing exit because i'm doing the same thing in my code and it worked:

```
... id="{{ values.0.vat }}" onclick="callAjax.call(this)" ...
```

This is an example code that i've used in one of my project and it correctly show the id in inspect.

Comment: the weired thing is that in the href the code exit and i.first_name render something ..

Comment: @Ben2pop Just for the sake of trying to find a solution, have you tried show the same thing in an other html object? try do the same thing but instead of <a> use, i don't know, another <div> and see if something change!

Comment: @Ben2pop another test i would do is to temporary delete the class and see if you obtain another result. I've tried again and i am able to assign and id to <a> (like expected)! Are you sure that the code posted is the same you are using?